# Can I set list view as the default in Pantheon Files?

Tags: release-loki, pantheon-files, default

A search here at StackExchange, at Reddit & via Google yields no clear answer. Has anyone found a way to force list view as the default view?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to click "View as List" and it will be your default

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried that, but the choice didn't survive reboot on my install of Loki.

Comment: Maybe you need to manually set /org/pantheon/files/preferences/default-viewmode to "list"

Comment: That's what I discovered. (See my answer to myself, below.)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version, this setting may be at the new location /io/elementary/files/files/default-viewmode.  This changes to the mode of the currently active tab or last tab closed (which will be the end one if you have more than one).

Tabs will restore with the mode they had when the app closed.  Default viewmode is used when you press the `+` button to create a new tab or if you create a new tab using `<Ctrl>-T` or the `Duplicate tab` option.

You might like to monitor this setting with dconf-editor while using Files to see its behaviour.

Comment: In older versions there is a behaviour where icon mode is automatically used when a folder containing icons was opened - regardless of the default mode. This behaviour has now been discontinued.

Comment: Thanks, Jeremy. See my answer of 27 Jan, above.

Answer (score -2):

Ask and I shall receive ... Five minutes later, I found my answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/134371/how-do-i-set-default-view-to-list-in-nautilus-file-manager

Comment: Nop, Nautilus isn't the file manager in elementary OS.